# AdMob - "No ad returned from any ad server" error

Tags: ios, admob, ionic3, cordova-admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm using Ionic 3 with admob-free plugin. Test reward ad doesn't show on iOS device.
It works on simulator, when I build it to my device, **LOAD_FAIL** event returns:

```
{"isTrusted":false,"error":"No ad returned from any ad server.","adType":"rewardVideo"}
```

**My Admob settings:**

- Frequency capping: disabled
- eCPM floor: disabled

**Mediation settings** (I set mediation after problem occured)

- location: all countries and territories
- status: enabled
- ad sources: AdMob Network

I haven't install another plugin after cordova-plugin-admob-free. Do I need  another ad sources/adapters etc?

or will it work when published.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

When I click
Settings > Privacy > Advertising > Reset Advertising Identifier
from my device, it works for the first try but it fails on the second attempt.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but it won't even work on the simulator. Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Settings > Privacy > Advertising > Reset Advertising Identifier worked for me. Now it works without doing it.